# Issue using axios post in aws lambda nodejs function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios

I'm using nodeJS on a lambda function.

I'm trying to post a request but it only works when running it locally but not when deployed on aws.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
let token = await axios.post(
   url,
   {clientSecret: 123,clientId: 456},
   { headers: { AppId } }
).catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

I think it may have to do with the body being a string vs JSON etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you run it locally, you may be on a corporate network. if you run from lambda, you are in the public space....to run on a corp network you would need to create VPCs and configure lambda to use those VPCs. or, poke a hole in the firewall...bad advice, ikid ikid

Comment: @LostJon thanks for your comment, I actually passed the wrong credentials to my api post that messed it all up